# Permalink-safe way to link pages inside footer.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently building a new theme for my site and am kind of stuck not knowing the proper way to link pages together. What is the proper way to direct visitor to another page if I were to write the link straight into `footer.php`?

Let's consider the following inside footer.php:

```
?>
    <a href="/a-link/">A Link</a>
<?php
```

That would work well up until I were to change my permalink structure to something else.

What is the proper way to do it(without using WP built in menus or anything similar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get_permalink` assuming your pages are in Wordpress.

See this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is 100% correct, but to save people some time when they stumble upon this question, I took the liberty of writing it out.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(12); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(12); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(12); ?></a>
```

This covers everything from hover text to dynamic page title, so if you decide to change "Contact" to "Contact Us," you won't have to remember to update the `footer.php` file.